# parent object mouse events not fired when mouse is over the inner object in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a rectangle in my XAML which acts as container of a textbox (textbox is displayed on the rectangle), I can move rectangle by dragging it (using mousedown and mousemove events of rectangle object), but there is a problem with textbox as it covers a big part of my rectangle, so when users click on mouse (and try to move it), there is a huge chance that they click actually on the textbox, so rectangle mouse events don't fire up and nothing works! (i.e. no move is possible). How can I overcome this problem? (I use SL 5 & VS 2012)

Comment: Are you doing this by arranging the textbox and rectangle on a canvas or some other way?

Comment: Try AddHandler method for your rectangle:  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899(v=vs.95).aspx  
use handledEventsToo = true

Comment: I think I already had a similar problem. Witch event are you listen? I think "Preview" events does what you want.

Comment: what do you mean by preview events? I use mousemove, leftbuttondown & leftbuttonup

Comment: I thought the preview events were only available in WPF

Answer (score 1):

The TextBox control handles the mouse down events and stops them from bubbling up the visual tree. (if you're using a canvas though bubbling events won't help)

You can add your own event handler to the mouse events through code e.g.

```
txtbox.AddHandler(TextBox.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, 
                  new MouseButtonEventHandler(<your handler>), true);
```

where your handler has the signature:

```
  private void <your handler>(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Let me know if the particulars of your situation require something more than this.

Comment: I use a canvas and everything is located on my canvas, so what is going wrong here?

Comment: If textbox and rectangle are children of canvas, use this handler to canvas.

Comment: Silverlight uses event bubbling, this is where an event is first given to the "child" in the visual tree and bubbles up. http://www.kirupa.com/net/event_bubbling_tunneling.htm has a good explanation. Using a canvas as i assume you have, your textbox will not be a visual child of the rectangle. However, this isn't the problem; the textbox handles the mouse events, meaning the event will not bubble further up the visual tree anyway. Adding a handler to textbox as I've outlined above will let you pick up the event without affecting the textboxes existing behaviour